# Navigation of a box using object oriented

Tags: javascript, oop, game-physics, p5.js

I don't know anyone will be patient to understand this long article and write some answers but I decided to write. Thanks :)

> I am trying to make 8x8 table game by the way.
>
> These are the global variables: selected(bool), i,j(int),box(only one), boxes(array of objects) and w(int, it is width of a box. I assigned 50 to w)
>   the Box is like selector to choose other boxes to update its x,y values.
>
> It has x,y coordinates and r,g,b means color that I use on it. xspeed and yspeed will use navigation of the boxes with naviga() and update() function
>
> My 'box' class is like that

```
class box
{
    constructor(x,y,r,g,b)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.xspeed=1;
        this.yspeed=0;
        this.r=r;
        this.g=g;
        this.b=b;
    }

    show()
    {
        fill(this.r,this.g,this.b); // these are standard p5 functions 
        rect(this.x,this.y,w,w);
    }

    updateXy()
    {
        this.x = this.x + this.xspeed;
        this.y = this.y + this.yspeed;


        this.x=0;
        else if(this.x<0)
        this.x=350;
        if(this.y>=400)
        this.y=0;
        else if(this.y<0)
        this.y=350;
```

**400 350 etc. events are fixes any box that escaping outside of the table(in 8x8) [[ 8 x w(50) = 400 ]]**

```
    }

    naviga(x,y)
    {
        this.xspeed=x;
        this.yspeed=y;
    }
}
```

> On setup() function I added my objects that I will use.

```
    let k=0;
    while(k<19)
    {
        for(i=5;i<8;i++)//To understand look to picture.
            for(j=5;j<8;j++)//This two for lines represent the 9 boxes at the bottom
            {
                boxes.push(new kutu(j*w,i*w,92,92,214));
                //It pushes box objects which have 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 indexes
            }


        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                boxes.push(new kutu(j*w,i*w,222,55,111));
                //It pushes box objects which have 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 indexes
            }
        k++;
    }
    box = new box(250,250,126,12,55); // It pushes the last box which have 20th index of array
```

> And all the boxes objects and the box object are have x,y values.

This is my keyPressed():

> ```
>     function keyPressed()
> {
>     if(keyCode === UP_ARROW)
>     {
>         box.naviga(0,-w);
> ```
>
> naviga() says substract -w(means 50) from box's y coordinate. Other
>    naviga usings are the same as this. if (w,0) or (-w,0) then change that specific box's x.
>
> ```
>         box.updateXy();
>         if(selected===true)
>         {
>             boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].naviga(0,-w);
>             boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].updateXy();
>         }
>     }
>
>     else if(keyCode === LEFT_ARROW)
>     {
>         box.naviga(-w,0);
>         box.updateXy();
>         if(selected===true)
>         {
>             boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].naviga(-w,0);
>             boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].updateXy();
>         }
>     }
>
>     else if(keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW)
>     {
>         box.naviga(w,0);
>         box.renew();
>         if(selected===true)
>         {
>             boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].naviga(w,0);
>             boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].updateXy();
>         }
>     }
>
>     else if(keyCode === DOWN_ARROW)
>     {
>         box.nav(0,w);
>         box.renew();     
>         if(selected===true)
>         {
>             boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].naviga(0,w);
>             boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].updateXy();
>         }
>
>     }
>     else if(keyCode === ENTER)
>     {
>         selected=true;
>     }
> }
> ```

and This is my pos() function that finds the index value that I have created as a box before.

**For example,
boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].naviga(0,w);
boxes[pos(box.x/w,box.y/w)].updateXy(); codes are decides where did 'selector box' go**

[image: Example]

```
function pos(a,b)
{
    let qval=-1;
    for(let n=5;n<8;n++)
    {
        for(let m=5;m<8;m++)
            {
                qval++;
                if(m===b && n===a)
                {
                    console.log(m + " " + n +" " + qval);
                    console.log("son = " + qval);
                }
                 break;

            }
            break;
        }
            return qval;
}
```

In draw() function which loop forever
I show grid table and show boxes with show() function at the top

And the problem is that I tried to show. I hope you'll understand this.

[image]

How can I access the other box objects

Comment: You'll have better luck if you [break your problem down into smaller parts](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

When you are in front of a problem like that. You must start to isolate the problem. It will help you to figure out what's wrong. And you will be able to post a smaller questions. So the goal is to remove all the code that does not cause the problem.

Also, your code must be complete. I've tried to copy the code you've posted. And it was impossible to run it (missing parts, unknow classes and functions, eg. `new kutu(...)` )

In these conditions nobody can help you. Take two minutes to read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), edit you question, and it will be all good.

Comment: Sorry for the 'kutu' name. I used turkish named variables, then I translate to english to make understand more people. I thought to write this place. This spend my at least 45 minutes to write. But when I focusing to get answer, it was already gone. This is so long, I got that nobody can help but again thank you for trying. This keep waiting for a while. But a few days later I will look it. Thanks